# C++ - Escaping or disabling backslash on string

Tags: c++, character, backslash

I am writing a C++ program to solve a common problem of message decoding. Part of the problem requires me to get a bunch of random characters, including '\', and map them to a key, one by one.

My program works fine in most cases, except that when I read characters such as '\' from a string, I obviously get a completely different character representation (e.g. '\0' yields a null character, or '\' simply escapes itself when it needs to be treated as a character).

Since I am not supposed to have any control on what character keys are included, I have been desperately trying to find a way to treat special control characters such as the backslash as the character itself.

My questions are basically these:

- Is there a way to turn all special characters off within the scope of my program?
- Is there a way to override current digraphs definitions of special characters and define   them as something else (like digraphs using very rare keys)?
- Is there some obscure method on the String class that I missed which can force the actual character on the string to be read instead of the pre-defined constant?

I have been trying to look for a solution for hours now but all possible fixes I've found are for other languages.

Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: "\" is special *only within a string/charater **literal*** -- not external data read in: it has *no inherent meaning* as the content of a `string` object! The `@"\verbatim\string\"` literal can be used (and the char literal `'\\'` is a trivial case), but once again, this only affects a *literal* value occurring in source. (This does not preclude that special meaning is attached to "\" in the external data source. And, indeed in certain sources, such as in a Regexp, still has meaning.)

Comment: Where is your string coming from? Is it hardcoded? User input? File IO?

Comment: "_I obviously get a completely different character representation_" It may be obvious to you but I have no idea what that means. When you read a character you get a character, what's the exact problem?

Comment: "I obviously get a completely different character representation" It may be obvious to you but I have no idea what that means. When you read a character you get a character, what's the exact problem? -- I meant to say that within the string literal, character combinations are not read the way we read them (e.g. "\n" is not a subarray containing '\','n'). They do produce a character, but because I am trying to decode a message using exact characters, the character I get is useless.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. Since the input is supposed to come from a file, I have to use something like fstream to read from the file, so I thought that what I would import as a line would be treated the same way as a string literal coded in my program. Some random combinations from sample input I read had random occurrences of '\', followed by some other random character. I mainly need to treat that '\' as a \, or else the pattern I would get would not be the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you read in a string like `"\0"` from stdin or a file, it will be treated as two separate characters: `'\\'` and `'0'`. There is no additional processing that you have to do.

Escaping characters is only used for string/character literals. That is to say, when you want to hard-code something into your source code.